Reference for the lemma that, given $0<A<180^\circ$, function $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{\sin(A-x)}$ is injective for $0\leq x\leq A$
There is a geometry lemma used in my mathematical community which states:

Given an angle $A$, $0 < A < 180^\circ$, the function $$f(x) = \dfrac{\sin(x)}{\sin(A-x)}$$ is injective, for $0 \leq x \leq A$.

Is this lemma mentioned anywhere in literature, and what is its recognized name?

I doubt that has a name.
